# Autofill textfield based on other textfield

Tags: javascript, php, html

> JavaScript

```
    function changeInput() {
            var pname = document.getElementById("pname").value;
            if(pname == "Olive" || "olive") {
                var remark = "150, Sinker-Single Jersey, Micro Polyester-Dry Fit";
            }
            else if(pname == "Umber" || "umber") {
                var remark = "180, Matte - Mesh, Micro Polyester-Dry Fit";
            }
}
document.getElementById("remark").value = remark;
var pname = document.getElementById("pname");
pname.onchange = function() {
            changeInput();
}
pname.onkeyup = function() {
            changeInput();
}
```

> HTML

```
<input type="text" name="pname" id="pname" value="" placeholder="Product Name">
<input type="text" name="remark" id="remark" value="" placeholder="Product Name">
```

If I try to type to input Olive in the first input field then it must automatically fill the next input field. 
**The issue that I'm facing is that if try to enter Umber then also it fills the the data of Olive in the input field.**

[HTML Form. I've attached the image link, if you see the image of the form my problem will be much more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ZzM.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is messed up!

Your first error is here :

```
if(pname == "Olive" || "olive")
```

This condition is always True! To test if `pname` is equal to `Olive` OR `olive`, your `If` statement should be :

```
if(pname == "Olive" || pname == "olive") {
```

This snippet will work.

```js
function changeInput() {
            var pname = document.getElementById("pname").value;
            var remark = "";
            if(pname == "Olive" || pname == "olive") {
                remark = "150, Sinker-Single Jersey, Micro Polyester-Dry Fit";
                document.getElementById("remark").value = remark;
            }
            else if(pname == "Umber" || pname == "umber") {
                remark = "180, Matte - Mesh, Micro Polyester-Dry Fit";
                document.getElementById("remark").value = remark;
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("remark").value = "";
            }
            
}


var pname = document.getElementById("pname");
pname.onkeyup = function() {
            changeInput();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="pname" id="pname" value="" placeholder="Product Name">
<input type="text" name="remark" id="remark" value="" placeholder="Product Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this -

```
<script>
   var pname = document.getElementById("pname").value;
 function changeInput() {

            var remark;
            if(pname == "Olive" || "olive") {
                remark = "150, Sinker-Single Jersey, Micro Polyester-Dry Fit";
            }
           if(pname == "Umber" || "umber") {
                remark = "180, Matte - Mesh, Micro Polyester-Dry Fit";
            }
            console.log("remark:"+remark);
            document.getElementById("remark").value = remark;
}
</script>
```

and HTML-

```
<input type="text" name="pname" id="pname" value="" onchange ="changeInput()" placeholder="Product Name">
<input type="text" name="remark" id="remark" value="" placeholder="Product Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var pname = document.getElementById("pname")
var remark = document.getElementById("remark");
pname.addEventListener('keyup',function(){


 if(pname.value == "Olive" || pname.value == "olive") {
              remark.value  = "150, Sinker-Single Jersey, Micro Polyester-Dry Fit";
            }
            else if(pname.value == "Umber" || pname.value == "umber" ) {
                remark.value = "180, Matte - Mesh, Micro Polyester-Dry Fit";
            } else{
               remark.value = "";
            }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="pname" id="pname" value="" placeholder="Product Name">
<input type="text" name="remark" id="remark" value="" placeholder="Product Name">
```